# I can't send the login form with angularJS to php file

Tags: php, json, linux, angularjs, apache

This is my controller that send the login form to php file:

```
blog.controller('AdminController',['$scope','$http','auth',function($scope,$http,auth) {
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
    $scope.admin;
    $scope.password;
    $scope.resultMessage;
    $scope.formData;
    $scope.submitted = false;
    $scope.submit = function(loginform){
        $scope.submitted = true;
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
        if(loginform.$valid){
            $http({
               method: 'POST',
               url: 'blog.php',
               headers:  { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
               data: $.param($scope.formData)
            }).success(function(data){
               console.log(data);
               if(data.success){
                   $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                   $scope.admin = data.admin;
                   $scope.password = data.password;
                   auth.login($scope.admin,$scope.password);
               }else{
                   $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                   $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                   $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
               }
            });
        }else{
            $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
            $scope.resultMessage = "Por favor introduzca todos los campos";
            $scope.result = "bg-danger";
        }
    }
}]);
```

But when I try login, it doesn't do anything and the debug browser shows me the code php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: promodominus
 * Date: 15/09/14
 * Time: 18:05
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');

if(isset($_POST['inputAdmin']) && isset($_POST['inputPassword'])){
    if(empty($_POST['inputAdmin']) && empty($_POST['inputPassword'])){
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Falta administrador o contraseña por poner, por favor pongalo');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    try{
        $conn = new MongoClient();
        $bd = $conn->blog;
        $coleccion = $bd->logo;
        $c_admin = array('admin'=>$_POST['inputAdmin']);
        $cursor = $coleccion->find($c_admin);
        $v_admin = $cursor->count();
        $c_password = array('password'=>$_POST['inputPassword']);
        $cursor = $coleccion->find($c_password);
        $v_password = $cursor->count();

        if($v_admin == 1 && $v_password == 1){
            $data = array('success' => true, 'admin' => $_POST['inputAdmin'], 'password' => $_POST['inputPassword']);
            echo json_encode($data);
        }else{
            $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'El usuario o la contraseña no es correcta');
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }catch(MongoConnectionException $e){
        die('Error al conectar con la base de datos');
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error al conectar con la base de datos');
        echo json_encode($data);
    }catch(MongoException $e){
        die('Error: '.$e->getMessage());
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Error:'.$e->getMessage());
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}else{
    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Por favor comprueba que esten rellenos los campos antes de logearse');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I think that the problem could be that I don't have installed some library in my apache server (My OS is Manjaro Linux) or It is that can't send form from localhost but I don't know.

Comment: have you checked if the php endpoint is receiving the params in the right format?

Comment: Joao Leal, this problem I had in other form but when I upload the code in my hosting server It run correctly. Because of this I think that the problem is that I don't have some apache library or php library install in my localhost server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was that I were using a environment with IDE Webstorm, but it run correctly in localhost. Well, that is an example to create a login form with AngularJS, PHP and MongoDB :)